# How to use Netbeans with ES2015?

Tags: netbeans, ecmascript-6, netbeans-8

How to use [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/) with [ES2015](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/)? I tried with version 8.0.1 and 8.0.2 of Netbeans, but the ES2015 sintaxe was not recognized.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I was surprised to learn that Netbeans [doesn't support ES6 yet](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=242387).

However, it appears that the support for Netbeans is scheduled for next month (September 2016) with the release of [Netbeans 8.2](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeans_82).